# How to replace NULL cell by NA in a tibble?

Tags: r, null, na, tibble

With a `tibble`, it is possible to have NULL cell with lists:

```
tibble(x = list(1L, NULL), y = 1:2)
```

which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x             y
  <list>    <int>
1 <int [1]>     1
2 <NULL>        2
```

that you can explore with `View()`

[image]

How could we replace all NULL cells of a tibble with NA?

The expected output is:

```
tibble(x = list(1L, NA), y = 1:2)
```

which produces:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x             y
  <list>    <int>
1 <int [1]>     1
2 <lgl [1]>     2
```

but is in fact:

[image]

---

I have tried:

```
is.null(df)
```

but it does not behave like `is.na()`...

---

Then I came with:

```
map(df, function(l) map(l, function(e) if(is.null(e)) NA else e))
```

But I struggle to make a new tibble with it:

```
do.call(as_tibble, map(df, function(l) map(l, function(e) if(is.null(e)) NA else e)))
```

that gives me an error:

```
Error: Columns 1 and 2 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `map` as

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(where(is.list), map, `%||%`, NA))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  x             y
  <list>    <int>
1 <int [1]>     1
2 <lgl [1]>     2
```

#### data

```
df <- tibble(x = list(1L, NULL), y = 1:2)
```

Comment: Great, I was not aware of the `%||%` operator from `rlang`.

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x = list(1L, NULL), y = 1:2)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.list), ~ purrr::modify_if(.x, is.null, ~ NA)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   x             y
#>   <list>    <int>
#> 1 <int [1]>     1
#> 2 <lgl [1]>     2
```